# Base and derived class allocation

Tags: c++

In the code below, `drvdCls` derives from `bseCls`. This code compiles and runs as it is. I however find an issue here: `newBse` will get deallocated after `Test()` exits. Am I right?

```
bseCls* Test()
{

    bseCls* newBse = new drvdCls();
    drvdCls newDrvd;
    newBse = &newDrvd;
    return newBse;

}
```

Comment: No, it won't. That's the whole point of dynamic memory allocation. You have severe problems in the code, though - you loose the pointer to the memory you've allocated and return a pointer to an automatic variable (which will be deallocated upon func exit and you'll end up in addressing freed memory in function invoker).

Comment: @icepack `newBse` is just a pointer, and by the time it is returned it points to a local variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza that's right, but that's not the question being asked

Answer (score 4):

The object originally pointed to by `newBse` will be leaked.  When you assigned the address of `newDrvd` to `newBse` you are losing the pointer to the heap-allocated object, and you will not be able to `delete` it.  This memory will be unusable until the process terminates.

Additionally, you are returning the address of a stack-allocated object as a pointer, which is bad for two reasons:

1. The object's destructor will have been called before the function returns, meaning you would be using a pointer to a destructed object.
2. The memory allocated for the object lives on the stack and will almost certainly be clobbered by future function calls.  At that point, your pointer will be point at something that is not a `bseCls`, but you will be using it as though it were.

If you use the pointer returned by this function, you are invoking undefined behavior and your program has license to do *anything*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be automatically deallocated. Every call to `new` must be matched by a call to `delete`. But that's not the only problem with your code, you're also returning the address of a local variable from the function.

```
newBse = &newDrvd; // memory leak, pointer to previously allocated object is lost
return newBse;     // newDrvd is destroyed when function exits, so returned
                   // pointer points to invalid memory
```

What you probably want to do is

```
bseCls* Test()
{
    return new drvdCls();
}
```

Now the caller must call `delete` on the returned pointer after using it. What you should do is

```
std::unique_ptr<bseCls> Test()
{
    return new drvdCls();
}
```

Now the allocated object will automatically be `delete`d when the returned `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: Note that `std::unique_ptr<>` is only available from C++11 on.  Depending on how this function is used, one of `std::auto_ptr<>` or `boost::shared_ptr<>` will be a good alternative for older C++ versions.